# Finding a sequence of refining partitions of $[0,t].$

Tags: real-analysis

Is it possible to give a sequence of refined partitions $\{P_{n}\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ of $[0,t],$ $t\in\mathbb{R},$ such that $\cup_{n}P_{n}$ is a dense set of $[0,t]$?

A partition $\mathcal{P}$ of $[0,t]$ is defined as $\mathcal{P}=\{0=t_{0}<t_{1}<\cdots<t_{n}=t\}.$

I think this possible because intuitively, every point $x\in[0,t]$ is a limit of a sequence of rational numbers, for example, in such interval, but I don't get a way to do that.

Comment: Just divide each interval in half to form the next partition.

Comment: What's a refined partition?

Comment: @Cauchy I'm not sure about the terminology in English, but it's something like this. Given two partitions $P$ and $Q$, $P$ is said to be "more refined" than $Q$ if $Q\subseteq P$. A sequence of refined partitions would be a $\subseteq$-increasing sequence of partitions.

Comment: @GitGud oh, so for each $n$, $P_{n+1}$ is a refinement of $P_n$? That's exactly what a refinement means in English, I just didn't understand the phrasing of OP (it could have been better!)

Comment: @Cauchy Yes. A "refinement", got it. "More refined" just didn't feel right. Thanks.

Comment: How could I prove, with your idea, that $\cup_{n}\mathcal{P}_{n}$ is dense @User8128? If $x$ is any point in $[0,t]$, how can I assure that $B_{\epsilon}(x)\cap\cup_{n}\mathcal{P}_{n}$ is not empty?

Comment: @MylittleSquid I will add an answer

Answer (score 1):

To expound on my very terse comment: let $$P_0 = \{ 0, t \}, P_1 = \{0, t/2, t\}, P_2 = \{0,t/4,t/2,3t/4,t\},\dots, P_n= \{kt/2^n : k=0,\ldots,2^n\}.$$ Note that each $P_n$ contains $P_{n-1}$ so these are successive refinements.

Here is the idea: take any $x \in [0,t]$. What is the largest possible distance from $x$ to $P_0?$ Well $x$ must lie in at least one of $[0,t/2]$ or $[t/2, t]$ which means that either $0$ or $t$ is distance $t/2$ (or less) away from $x$. That is: there is a point in $P_0$ no further than $t/2$ form $x$. What about $P_1?$ Well, $x$ must lie in at least one of $$[0,t/4], [t/4, t/2], [t/2,3t/4], [3t/4,t]$$ which means that one of $0,t/2,t$ is distance $t/4$ or less away from $x$. That is: there is a point in $P_1$ no further than $t/4$ from $x$. Similarly, there is a point in $P_n$ no further than $t/2^{n+1}$ away from $x$. Since we are taking the union over all $n$, $t/2^{n+1}$ becomes arbitrarily small, so there is a point in $\cup_n P_n$ which is arbitrarily close to $x$.

I'll let you fill in the gaps for a rigorous proof; the easiest way to do so is to 'zoom in' to each interval which $x$ falls into. For example, we remarked that $x \in [0,t/2]$ or $x \in [t/2,t]$. Now consider only the half interval which $x$ is in and repeat the process.

As a final note, this same sort of idea is used in root finding (there it is called the bisection method: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bisection_method). The proof that the bisection method works is very similar to this proof.

Answer (score 0):

Let $A = (\mathbb Q \cap [0,t]) \cup \{t\}$. $A$ is countable, so write $A = \{r_1 = 0, r_2 = t, r_3,r_4,\ldots\}$, and let $P_n  = \{r_1,r_2,\ldots, r_n\}$, $n \ge 3$.

Comment: It seems to me that OP wants a sequence of partitions, each a refinement of the last.

Comment: @User8128 isn't this what I did in my answer?

Comment: Ah yes, this is what you did. My apologies, I misread.